# JOOMLA 1.5 Connecting to the admin not possible

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I just take over the site of an association which has many problems with its website.
This is based on Joomla 1.5, the goal for me is to migrate the site to 2.5. The first problem I encounter is level access to the administration area, I tells my login / password and after validation I fall on the login page without any error message. I thought I had found an initial response here http://www.joomlaspan.com/general/recover-super-administrator-status-of-joomla-10x-and-15x.php anything but I actually still have the same worries. And I really do not understand where does the concern, I'm sure of my username. Someone may have an idea of the origin of this problem?

[image: content of modules directory]
[image: content of plugins directory]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have full setup or you just have plugins,modules and components?

Comment: I have not been able to access the admin area of cms, but I can give you the contents of directories modules and plugins:
http://i.imgur.com/Tymb80O.png
http://i.imgur.com/ykD5AiJ.png

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of, try cleaning the browser cookies.(this fixed for me once), see if only some IP can access to the directory on the htaccess file, and final do all from scratch, joomla 1.5.X is really bad! :P

Comment: I just reinstalled joomla 1.5 and with the old database, the connection works, but I still do not know why it works not on the version that is in production

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have taken over the website, I assume you have full access to the hosting control panel aswell. If not, get it, else there isn't much point in being able to run a website without access to everything.

If you do have it, then go to PHPMyAdmin, then go to the `#__users` table and ensure your user has the correct permissions and belongs to the correct usergroup. If no changes need to be made, then I would suggest creating a subdomain, installing a fresh copy of Joomla, open up your username row and copy all the details from the new one to the old site.

Comment: I have all the access on the website (mysql and ftp)